# Algorithm to concatenate rows into matrix with a specified column space

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Say there exists a set `X` of row vectors, each with dimension `1 x m`, and a set `Y` of column vectors, each with dimension `n x 1`.

We select `n` row vectors from the set `X`, concatenating into a matrix with dimension `n x m`. I'm interested in finding matrices where the resulting concatenated matrix can also be made by concatenating `m` column vectors from `Y`.

**Is there an algorithm** that can **return all such matrices** satisfying the condition that the resulting matrix can be made by a concatenation of rows **AND** also can be made by a concatenation of columns? For instance:

```
X = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
Y = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]).T
```

Then one such matrix that can be made from a concatenation of 3 rows and 3 columns is:

```
M = 
[[1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Could you please provide X and Y valid?

Comment: X appears with a }

Comment: Y does not make sense to me, what is that? any examples or similar?

Comment: Fixed {}. What is your confusion about Y? Y is some arbitrary set of column vectors, X is some arbitrary set of row vectors.

Comment: `[1, 0, 0].T`isn't valid Python.  A list does not have a `T` attribute.  `T` also doesn't change a 1d array either.

Comment: Are the element of each row, vector only 1s and 0s?

Comment: @batlike lists are unhashable, hence, you cannot have a set of lists. Do you mean to have a list of lists?

Comment: The element in each row, vectors are either 1's and 0's. @ Ehsan, yes - I'll edit it into a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your X and Y are arrays. If not, simply convert them to numpy arrays first.

```
X = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
Y = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]).T
```

Then your problem basically translates to finding which rows of X match with which columns of Y. Once you find all matching rows-column pairs, then you can take any subset of matching rows/columns as your submatrices (if your arrays are only 0 and 1, you can make them binary and use bitwise and/or):

```
matching_rows = X[(X[:,None]==Y.T[None,:]).all(-1).any(-1)]
```

out:

```
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Now any combinations of these rows from X has a corresponding presence in columns of Y. Now, if you need to keep the order of rows as they appear in X, take all combinations of rows with the same order as above, otherwise, take all the permutations of subsets of rows from above. For example in the above case, the corresponding submatrices would be:

```
from itertools import combinations 
n = matching_rows.shape[0]
#all possible combinations of matches
subsets = [list(combinations(np.arange(n), i)) for i in range(1, n)]
#[[(0,), (1,), (2,)], [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]]


#all matching submatrices
[matching_rows[list(j)]  for i in subsets for j in i]
```

out:

```
[array([[1, 0, 1]]), array([[1, 0, 0]]), array([[1, 1, 1]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]), array([[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]])]
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not address the original problem. In the output, the second column [0, 0, 1] is not in the specified column space.

Comment: @batlike Those are not columns of Y! Those are rows of X as the name of the variable `matching_rows` suggest. All the **ROWS** in there match the columns of Y. Also, I suggest reading the post along the output, that might give you insight on how this solution works. Thank you.

Comment: I see. This is a more complete answer than the other, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @batlike Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Casting the sets as arrays:

```
In [290]: X = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
In [291]: X
Out[291]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])
In [292]: Y = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
In [293]: Y
Out[293]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [294]: Y.T
Out[294]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

From that it's easy to see the your `M` example is a subset of rows or columns:

```
In [295]: X[[0,1,2],:]
Out[295]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
In [297]: Y.T[:,[0,2,4]]
Out[297]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

So I can imagine the problem as one of searching for 2 indexing array that work.  The brute force way would  generate all such combos and test which works.  In a sense that's the "vectorize" numpy way :)   But it's probably faster to do some sort of tree search, backtracking when a partial selection fails.  But search problems like that are not a strong suit for `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

0. Select between X and Y the smaller for 1)
1. Create your Matrix from Xs elements (as in point 0) but for simplicity let's imagine is X). So you have FromXmatrix which is a n x m matrix.
2. Take FromXmatrix and split into columns.
3. Checks if that columns are on Y, if False discard this chase, if yes save that solutions as valid
4. Go back to 1) until all possible valid combinations of X are checked.

You could do the same than above but using all possible combinations from Y and checking if they yield a solution valid in terms of the elements of X.

Comment: Yes, this is one possible solution but it is iterative and slow. It relies on generating all possible row permutations, and checking if the resulting columns exist in some set. I am currently employing this strategy, but for a large row space this is computationally intractable. I wonder if this is a solved problem/already an elegant algorithm published.

Comment: Which is the context of this? How do you know it if computationally intractable?